# Android app not processing JSON correctly

Tags: android, json

```
package com.example.editartist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtArtistType;
EditText txtPhoneNo;
EditText txtDescription;
Button btnSave;
Button btnDelete;

String uid="1";

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


private static final String url_profile_details = "http://10.0.2.2/android_main/get_profile_details.php";


private static final String url_update_profile = "http://10.0.2.2/android_main/update_profile.php";


private static final String url_delete_profile = "http://10.0.2.2/android_main/delete_profile.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PROFILE = "profile";
private static final String TAG_UID = "uid";
private static final String TAG_ARTIST_TYPE = "artist_type";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_NO = "phone_no";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // save button
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    new GetProfileDetails().execute();

    // save button click event
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to update profile
            new SaveProfileDetails().execute();
        }
    });

    // Delete button click event
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // deleting profile in background thread
            new DeleteProfile().execute();
        }
    });

}

class GetProfileDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading profile details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));

                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_profile_details, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Profile Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received profile details
                        JSONArray profileObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PROFILE); // JSON Array

                        // get first profile object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject profile = profileObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // profile with this uid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtArtistType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputArtistType);
                        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPhoneNo);
                        txtDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDescription);

                        // display profile data in EditText
                        txtArtistType.setText(profile.getString(TAG_ARTIST_TYPE));
                        txtPhoneNo.setText(profile.getString(TAG_PHONE_NO));
                        txtDescription.setText(profile.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                    }else{
                        // profile with uid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to  Save profile Details
 * */
class SaveProfileDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving profile ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Saving profile
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // getting updated data from EditTexts
        String artistType = txtArtistType.getText().toString();
        String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
        String description = txtDescription.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_UID, uid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ARTIST_TYPE, artistType));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PHONE_NO, phoneNo));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

        // sending modified data through http request
        // Notice that update profile url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_profile,
                "POST", params);

        // check json success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("UPDATE","Successfully updated");
            } else {
                // failed to update profile
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once profile updated
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

class DeleteProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Profile...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        int success;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_profile, "POST", params);

            Log.d("Delete Profile", json.toString());

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("DELETE","Successfully deleted");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
}



package com.example.editartist;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

The app will show Loading Profiles dialog for two seconds and then it simply closes like: EditArtist has stopped working. There is long list of errors in the log starting with

```
10-05 10:53:33.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 10:53:33.000:E/AndroidRuntime(1057): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

I have taken uid="1" for the sake of ease here and so only the user with uid=1 can be edited.

Comment: You can't invoke network requests on the main thread

Comment: @UdiI What exactly should I change in my code?

Comment: remove the `runOnUIThread()` part from `doInBackground` of `GetProfileDetails` class and move the code in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: UI changes should be in postexecute..instead doinbackground..

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {}
});
```

from the asynctask`s **doInBackground().**

Asynctask is itself is a thread in which you are doing network operations.If you write runonUiThread() on doinBackground then the network operation will perform in the main thread only and it will encounter the exception that you are facing.Hence there will be no point of writting an asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run network request in Main UI thread...to process JSON properly you have run it on different thread using `new Thread` or use `AsynTask`